# Changing styles with delay

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to switch the styles of the div with some delay after the button click.

The code will work fine if I simply will use something like `this.customEffect = 'blueborder';` without timeouts.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    customEffect: ''
  },
  methods: {
    start: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        this.customEffect = 'blueborder';
      }, 1000);
      setTimeout(function() {
        this.customEffect = 'redtext';
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.blueborder {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.redtext {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button @click="start">Start</button>
    <div :class="customEffect">Some text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is the `this` context in your timeouts is the anonymous function's, not the parent object. You can use either arrow functions or an explicit binding.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    customEffect: ''
  },
  methods: {
    start: function() {
      setTimeout((function() { //BIND
        this.customEffect = 'blueborder';
      }).bind(this), 1000);
      setTimeout(() => { //OR =>
        this.customEffect = 'redtext';
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.blueborder {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.redtext {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button @click="start">Start</button>
    <div :class="customEffect">Some text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

*EDIT* Recommended learning resources

`this` can get pretty tricky in JS. If you want to learn more about it I highly recommend the relevant [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) book by Getify [This & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use boostrap to avoid making code that already have the boostrap features.

Or you can make you own css classes:

For example:

```
.animated {
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.fast {
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-duration: 0.4s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
from {
  opacity: 0;
}

to {
  opacity: 1;
}
}

.fadeIn {
animation-name: fadeIn;
```

html example:

```
<div class="animated fadeIn fast">
  <h1 class="display-4">My app</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a great app!</p>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method debounce of lodash.
https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce

```
 methods: {
        start: _.debounce(function() {
            this.customEffect = (this.customEffect == 'redtext')?'blueborder':'redtext';
        },1000)
      }
```

before you need to import lodash

Comment: Thank you, Daniel but I am trying to learn Vue so using other libs is not something I was searching for